# Ruby splat usage

Tags: ruby, arrays, splat

I came across an illustration of this in a text but when I tried it in my IRB shell I get an error. Is this following code legal? OTherwise is there a shorthand way to do get the middle array (say median of 1 or 2 elements assuming a sorted array).

```
irb(main):004:0> first, *middle, last = [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]
SyntaxError: compile error
(irb):4: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting '='
first, *middle, last = [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47]
           ^
from (irb):4
from :0
```

Comment: Ruby version? It works for me. I am on 2.1.4 currently.

Comment: This code is correct. Try to restart your `irb`.

Comment: My version is 0.9.5 for irb..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you are using ruby 1.8.7.    That syntax requires at least 1.9.2 or so.

I know the system ruby that ships with a lot of systems is still 1.8.7, but it is not supported any more and you really should install ruby 2.x.